# Extracting Coq to Haskell while keeping comments

Tags: haskell, comments, coq

**Is there anyway to keep comments while extracting Coq to Haskell**?
Ideally, I would like to have machine generated Haskell files untouched by humans, and so the motivation of extracting comments is clear. However, I couldn't find how to do it, and I wonder if this is at all possible (?). Here is an example Coq file:

```
(*************)
(* factorial *)
(*************)
Fixpoint factorial (n : nat) : nat :=
  match n with
  | 0 => 1
  | 1 => 1 (* this case is redundant *)
  | S n' => (mult n (factorial n'))
  end.

Compute (factorial 7).

(********************************)
(* Extraction Language: Haskell *)
(********************************)
Extraction Language Haskell.

(***************************)
(* Extract to Haskell file *)
(***************************)
Extraction "/home/oren/Downloads/RPRP/output.hs" factorial.
```

And when I extract it to Haskell everything works fine other than the fact that the comment inside factorial is lost:

```
$ coqc ./input.v > /dev/null
$ cat ./output.hs
module Output where

import qualified Prelude

data Nat =
   O
 | S Nat

add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add n m =
  case n of {
   O -> m;
   S p -> S (add p m)}

mul :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
mul n m =
  case n of {
   O -> O;
   S p -> add m (mul p m)}

factorial :: Nat -> Nat
factorial n =
  case n of {
   O -> S O;
   S n' ->
    case n' of {
     O -> S O;
     S _ -> mul n (factorial n')}}
```

Comment: This might not always be possible – consider the comment `(* -} *)`. Would that be converted to `{- -} -}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.  To double-check, you can see that [the AST for the internal language that extraction targets](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/v8.9/plugins/extraction/miniml.ml), called MiniML, doesn't (as of v8.9) have any constructors for comments.  The relevant file is in the Coq repository, [`plugins/extraction/miniml.ml`](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/v8.9/plugins/extraction/miniml.ml).